# "ambiguous reference to overloaded definition" when using Java class in Scala

Tags: java, scala, reflection, scala-generics

I am using a Java class in my Scala which generates `ambiguous reference to overloaded definition`. Here is the code to explain this problem.

IComponent.java

```
package javascalainterop;

import java.util.Map;

public interface IComponent {
    public void callme(Map<String, Object> inputMap);
}
```

AComponent.java

```
package javascalainterop;

import java.util.Map;

public class AComponent implements IComponent {
     String message;
     public AComponent(String message) {
        this.message = message;
     }

     @Override
     public void callme(Map inputMap) {
        System.out.println("Called AComponent.callme with " + message);
    }
}
```

BComponent.scala

```
package javascalainterop

import java.util.{Map => JMap}

class BComponent(inputMessage: String) extends AComponent(inputMessage) {
    override def callme(inputMap: JMap[_, _]) {
        println(s"Called BComponent.callme with $inputMessage")
    }
}
```

ComponentUser.scala

```
package javascalainterop

import java.util.{HashMap => JHashMap}

object ComponentUser extends App {
    val bComponent = new BComponent("testmessage")
    val javaMap = new JHashMap[String, AnyRef]
    bComponent.callme(javaMap)
}
```

When I try to compile `BComponent.scala` and `ComponentUser.scala` the compilation fails with message below.

```
javascalainterop/ComponentUser.scala:8: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method callme in class BComponent of type (inputMap: java.util.Map[_, _])Unit
and  method callme in trait IComponent of type (x$1: java.util.Map[String,Object])Unit
match argument types (java.util.HashMap[String,AnyRef])
    bComponent.callme(javaMap)
                   ^
one error found
```

The Java classes represent a library which I have no control over. I have considered using reflection but it doesn't quite serve the use case. `super[AComponent].callme` also doesn't resolve the issue. How can the situation be resolved so that the code compiles and `AComponent.callme` is invoked at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED**

I've edited this answer significantly to resolve earlier confusion and to be more correct.

I think the original library that you're working with is broken, and not doing what it appears to be doing.

`IComponent` declares a method `void callme(java.util.Map<String, Object> inputMap)` (which is equivalent to `callme(inputMap: java.util.Map[String, AnyRef]: Unit` in *Scala*), while `AComponent` declares `void callme(java.util.Map inputMap)` (`callme(inputMap: java.util.Map[_, _]): Unit` in *Scala*).

That is, `IComponent.callme` accepts a *Java* `Map` whose key is a `String` and whose value is an `AnyRef`, while `AComponent.callme` accepts a *Java* `Map` whose key is *any type* and whose value is *any type*.

By default, the *Java* compiler accepts this without complaint. However, if compiled with the `-Xlint:all` option, the *Java* compiler will issue the warning:

```
javascalainterop/AComponent.java:12:1: found raw type: java.util.Map
  missing type arguments for generic class java.util.Map<K,V>
  public void callme(Map inputMap) {
```

However, there's a far bigger problem in this specific case than merely omitting `Map`'s type arguments.

Because the compile time signature of the `AComponent.callme` method differs from that of the `IComponent.callme` method, it now appears that `AComponent` provides two different `callme` methods (one that takes a `Map<String, Object>` argument, and one that takes a `Map` argument). Yet, at the same time, *type erasure* (the removal of generic type information at runtime) means that the two methods also look identical at runtime (and when using *Java* reflection). So, `AComponent.callme` overrides `IComponent.callme` (thereby fulfilling the `IComponent` interface's contract), while also making any subsequent calls to `Acomponent.callme` with a `Map<String, Object>` instance ambiguous.

We can verify this as follows: comment out the `callme` definition in `BComponent` and change the contents of the `ComponentUser.scala` file as follows:

```scala
package javascalainterop

import java.util.{HashMap => JHashMap}

object ComponentUser extends App {
  //val bComponent = new BComponent("testmessage")
  val javaMap = new JHashMap[String, AnyRef]
  //bComponent.callme(javaMap)

  // Test what happens when calling callme through IComponent reference.
  val aComponent = new AComponent("AComponent")
  val iComponent: IComponent = aComponent
  iComponent.callme(javaMap)
}
```

When run, the program now outputs:

```
Called AComponent.callme with AComponent
```

Great! We created an `AComponent` instance, converted it to an `IComponent` reference, and when we called `callme`, it was unambiguous (an `IComponent` only has a single method named `callme`) and executed the overridden version provided by `AComponent`.

However, what happens if we try to call `callme` on the original `aComponent`?

```scala
package javascalainterop

import java.util.{HashMap => JHashMap}

object ComponentUser extends App {
  //val bComponent = new BComponent("testmessage")
  val javaMap = new JHashMap[String, AnyRef]
  //bComponent.callme(javaMap)

  // Test what happens when calling callme through each reference.
  val aComponent = new AComponent("AComponent")
  val iComponent: IComponent = aComponent
  iComponent.callme(javaMap)
  aComponent.callme(javaMap)
}
```

Uh oh! This time, we get an error from the *Scala* compiler, which is a little more rigorous regarding type parameters than *Java*:

```
javascalainterop/ComponentUser.scala:14:14: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
 both method callme in class AComponent of type (x$1: java.util.Map[_, _])Unit
 and  method callme in trait IComponent of type (x$1: java.util.Map[String,Object])Unit
 match argument types (java.util.HashMap[String,AnyRef])
   aComponent.callme(javaMap)
              ^
```

Note that we haven't even looked at `BComponent` yet.

So far as I can tell , there is no way to workaround this ambiguity in *Scala*, since the two ambiguous functions are actually one and the same, and have the exact same signature at runtime (making reflection useless too). (If anyone knows otherwise, please feel free to add a comment!)

Since *Java* is happier with this generic nonsense than *Scala*, you might need to write all of the relevant code that uses this library in *Java*.

Otherwise, it looks like your only options are to:

- Report a bug in the original library (`AComponent.callme` should accept a `Map<String, Object>` argument—in *Java* terms—not just a `Map` argument), or
- Implement your own version of `AComponent` that works correctly, or
- Use an alternative library, or
- Implement your own library.

**UPDATE**

Having thought about it a little more, you might be able to achieve what you're looking to do with a little sleight of hand. Clearly, it will depend upon what you're trying to do, and the complexity of the actual `IComponent` and `AComponent` classes, but you might find it useful to change `BComponent` to implement `IComponent`, while using an `AComponent` instance in its implementation. This should work provided that `BComponent` doesn't have to be derived from `AComponent` (in `BComponent.scala`):

```scala
package javascalainterop

import java.util.{Map => JMap}

class BComponent(inputMessage: String) extends IComponent {

  // Create an AComponent instance and access it as an IComponent.
  private final val aComponent: IComponent = new AComponent(inputMessage)

  // Implement overridden callme in terms of AComponent instance.
  override def callme(inputMap: JMap[String, AnyRef]): Unit = {
    println(s"Called BComponent.callme with $inputMessage")
    aComponent.callme(inputMap)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer with great explanation. I am using an older version of a component indicated by AComponent and it basically needs rewriting to use type parameters across the board.